# JSF setting div class after validation exception

Tags: java, css, jsf

at the moment I've got a construct like this:

```
<div class="line">
   <label>Label</label>
   <h:inputText id="text-id1" required="true" ... />
</div>
```

Now when a validation exception is thrown I show them in a

```
<h:messages ... />
```

Is it possible to set the error class to my wrapping div?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div class="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity == null ? 'line' : 'errorLine'}">
```

Comment: is it possible to recieve a message for a UI component specific? Facescontext.getMessages(clientID) would match that but I wasn't able to get this by EL tried: #{facesContext.messages("id")} and #{facesContext.messages["id"]}

Comment: Just use `<h:message>` with a `for` attribute pointing to the component ID.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked, but i thought i should include it for completeness.

```
 <h:message errorClass="errorline" infoClass="line"/>
```